# R bygroup mice imputation - mice.impute.bygroup

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I would like to group my data by `state_id` and `species` when I run `mice::mice` to impute values. I've got it grouped by state_id and results are looking much better than without the bygroup.

[mice.impute.bygroup: Groupwise Imputation Function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/miceadds/versions/3.11-6/topics/mice.impute.bygroup)

Edit... improved, working code:

```r
# Modify df name and method
init <- mice::mice(data, method = "pmm", maxit = 0) 
meth <- init$meth
pred <- init$pred

# Impute variables by group (state_id)
imputationFunction <- list("decimalLatitude" = meth["decimalLatitude"],
                           "decimalLongitude" = meth["decimalLongitude"])

meth[c("decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude")] <- "bygroup"

group <- list("decimalLatitude" = "state_id", 
              "decimalLongitude" = "state_id")

# Remove variables as predictors but they can still be imputed.
pred[, c("coordinateUncertaintyInMeters", "geoprivacy_id")] <- 0

set.seed(500)
imp <- mice::mice(data, meth = meth, pred = pred, m = 1, 
                  group = group, imputationFunction = imputationFunction)
imp <- complete(imp)
```

This works too, but no bygroup:

```r
imp <- mice(data, m = 1, maxit = 3, method = 'norm.predict', seed = 500)
imp <- complete(imp, 1)
```

So, one question remains.

1. Can I group by multiple variables?

When I replace the variable state_id with species_id, I'm running into an error:

Error in lm.fit(x = x, y = y) : 0 (non-NA) cases

The problem seems to be that some species have zero or no values for lat and long data. I confirmed this for one state by removing all species with no lat and long data and the imputation by species was successful.

```r
group <- list("decimalLatitude" = "species_id", 
              "decimalLongitude" = "species_id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `mice.impute.bygroup` directly. It is a function that gets called when you specify `method["x"] <- "bygroup"`, just like you call `mice.impute.norm.predict` with `"norm.predict"` (see `?mice.impute.norm.predict`).

Below is some example code on how to use `bygroup`.

**Sample data**

```r
data <- iris
str(data)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

data[, -5] <- mice::ampute(data[, -5])$amp

init <- mice::mice(data, maxit = 0)
```

**Impute one variable (Petal.Width) by group (Species)**

```r
meth <- init$meth
pred <- init$pred

imputationFunction <- list("Petal.Width" = meth["Petal.Width"])
meth["Petal.Width"] <- "bygroup"
group <- list("Petal.Width" = "Species")

pred[, "Species"] <- 0

imp <- mice::mice(data, meth = meth, pred = pred, m = 1, 
                  group = group, imputationFunction = imputationFunction)
```

**For all variables**

```r
meth <- init$meth
pred <- init$pred

imputationFunction <- as.list(meth[meth != ""])
meth[meth != ""] <- "bygroup"
group <- imputationFunction
group[] <- "Species"

pred[, "Species"] <- 0

imp <- mice::mice(data, meth = meth, pred = pred, m = 1, 
                  group = group, imputationFunction = imputationFunction)
```

**Further considerations**

The `bygroup` method does not allow you to group across multiple variables. You could make a new variable that simply covers all those groups. Internally, all that `bygroup` does is split the data into distinct groups, so that's not a problem.

However, at some point you have to consider whether this is a proper way of doing things. It may be more worthwhile to consider [multi-level imputation](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Multi_level/Multi_level_data.html).

Comment: Things are looking really good. Can we group by more than one variable? I've update my question.

Comment: I had a look at the internals; it only works with 1 variable. You could consider making a new variable that combines the groupings of multiple variables. However, you may want to consider whether that is the best way to go forward. It could very well be that you should be looking into multi-level imputation instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. your example is better than any official documentation I came across. The rdocumentation had imputationFunction after the method and group lines and it failed in that order, so I used your order. I'm reasonably happy with the results I've got. Would have been great to group by species, but some species don't have enough data for the imputation to work out that way. I'll take a look at multi-level.